# the code doesn't stop running, in Java

Tags: java, primes

I'm solving problem 10 in project Euler in Java, which is

> "The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17. 
>   Find the sum of all the primes below two million."

and my code is

```
package projecteuler_1;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectEuler_1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int sum = 0, i = 2;
    while (i <= 2000000) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
 }

 public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    int i, res;
    boolean flag = true;
    for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        res = n % i;
        if (res == 0) {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
 }
}
```

but the code doesn't give me any results, it doesn't stop running. Why?

Comment: The code is in `O(n^2)`, it may take a long time. Are you sure it finished?

Comment: What does it print? Or are you saying it doesn't print anything at all? Try with a much smaller number first - as @Absurd-Mind says it may be taking a long time.

Comment: It must be taking time.

Comment: The reason it doesn't give you any result is that it's really badly optimized. Project Euler is about optimizing your algorithms to problems that need it, so your code is a prime example of a solution that is too simple to provide a solution. You need to work out another approach, but giving it as an answer would spoil the challenge.

Comment: It will finish, but will take a long time. You should think about some shortcuts to speed up your code. For example: Does `isPrime()` have to check for all numbers below `n` or is a subset enough? Maybe you can leave the function earlier? etc ...

Comment: @Absurd-Mind no it didnt finish although the code is right bY the way how did you know it is in O(n^2) ?? :)

Comment: Did you try debugging it? I'm with @Absurd-Mind I believe it is running, but very slowly. 2,000,000^2 = 4,000,000,000,000, which is a lot

Comment: @user3605253 Try a smaller number to see, if it actually runs correctly.

Comment: @user3605253 by looking at it. Two while/for loops indicate that it will be `n^2`. Try a smaller number or add a print inside of `if (isPrime(n)) { print...`

Comment: Do you know that BigInteger has his own method to check for primes? Check out [BigInteger::isProbablePrime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime%28int%29).

Comment: @طاهر no need, really. but you're welcome. -- Why delete your answer? I was hoping you'd made that one last correction so there is at least one correct code here and I could up-vote it. If you do, please ping me about it.

Comment: [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+primes+2000000+is%3Aquestion) gives ***15 questions*** asked and answered about this problem on SO, prior to this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I'm trying to find the sum of primes below 2 million in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553891/im-trying-to-find-the-sum-of-primes-below-2-million-in-java)

Comment: @user3605253 when confronted with an apparent non-termination issue, apply [***empirical orders of growth*** analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth). Run your program for some smaller `n`'s, where you'd get run times in 1..10..100 seconds range, then make the projection for *your* `n`. -- as for your code, make your `sum` a `long` variable, not `int`, and in the `isPrime()` function change the `for (i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {` to `for (i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {` and it will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making a small change, you can improve the performance tremendously:

Change:

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
```

To:

```
int max = Math.sqrt(n);
for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
```

You only need to check up to the square root of the number, because larger factors will already have been found on the way up.

Making this change will change your algorithm from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n log(n)) (I think). Your code isn't outputting anything because it's taking too long to run - the change should hopefully get you an answer within a reasonable time.

Comment: I'm tempted to ask why would OP want to check even numbers. If it doesn't divide with 2, why would it divide with 4? There are other problems in the solution as well but I think I'll leave that for OP to discover.

Comment: @eis there are other optimizations you could make too, but even the one you suggested won't change the big O number.

Comment: yeah, it doesn't. However I don't think we should be solving the problem for him as Project Euler is about individual learning, really. The hint that his algorithm is suboptimal should be enough I think.

Comment: It will be O(nsqrt(n)), **not** O(nlogn). I gave a detailed answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23361957/572670) for the reasoning.

Comment: Just FYI the stated problem is that it "doesn't stop running", not that it "gives wrong results". I believe I have answered the question as stated and provided a fix for it.

Comment: (this doesn't fix the OP code producing an incorrect result though... just mentioning it because this is an accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your code run time is `O(n^2)`. Each call to `isPrime()` is `O(n)` on average.

**Explanation:**

`1/2` of the numbers are divisable by 2, `1/3` are divisable by 3, ... `1/n` are divisable by `n`. The expected number of runs for this method will then be `(1-1/2) + (1-1/3) +...+(1-1/n) = (1+1+..+1)-(1/2+1/3+..+1/n) = n - (1/2+1/3+...+1/n)` The 2nd sum is the [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), and its sum is in `O(logn)`, so this gives you `O(n-logn)=O(n)` run time.

Since this is done per each number, it gives total of `O(n^2)`.

---

@Bohemian approach to change to `int max = Math.sqrt(n);` will yield `O(nsqrt(n))` performance, as described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23361957/572670).

---

The best approach in terms of time complexity is to use something like **[Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)**, which will yield `O(nlogn)` time performance, which is asymptotically better than your algorithm, and the optimized one, and thus will run significantly faster for large numbers.